# Is there a way to do batch processing for records during data retrieval in marklogic

Tags: marklogic

Currently we are trying improve performance using `xdmp:spawn-function` with 'query' as transaction-type.  So, lets say for a search criteria we have 90 documents and I am splitting it into 3 batches each with 30 records. Now I am sending 30 record ids inside `xdmp:spawn-function` and processing. Finally I am accumulating data for 3 batches. I am able get good performance doing so. But we are afraid that it might have negative impact of some thread waiting in tasks server of cluster.

Could you please suggest something to avoid spawn and still have parallel processing?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`xdmp:spawn-function`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:spawn-function) and give certain tasks lower/higher priority than others using [options](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:spawn#options). You could give normal priority to your batches and higher priority to more critical tasks to prevent waiting in the task server.

Alternatively, if you index the data you are batching, you can use aggregate functions to accumulate data, and these functions are executed in parallel across the cluster. There are many built in aggregate functions, like [max](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:max)/[min](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:min), [sum](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:sum-aggregate), etc. If there the aggregate function you need doesn't exist out of the box, it's also possible to write your own: https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/aggregateUDFs

Comment: Thanks Mads Hansen. But my use case is little different. And here it is.

Comment: Lets say we have 90 actual document ids  and for each document id we have more than one version of documents in ML and lets take total number of versions for 90 document id is 1000 (each version has its own unique id). So, i am splitting 90 document ID into 3 batch and processing. Final outcome is 90 xml document. It is element wise summarization based on number of versions for a document ID. If a document id has 6 versions , then final summarized version should be prepared out of 6 versions using some calculation.

Comment: @TanmaySarkar If this operation needs to read 1000 documents from the database, then it is likely to be IO bound, specifically the forests. The query to select your documents will take a trivial amount of time, and the majority will be spent reading from disk. I would recommend you look into optimizing that.